# Play 4 videos at once

Tags: windows-7, macos, multiple-monitors, video-playback

For a number of reasons not worth saying I need to play 4 videos at the exactly same time on 4 different screens. I already tried a few softwares like vidlord (that plays 4 videos at the same time but doesnt let you reorganize the screens), tried oppening several VLC instances and playing the videos through hotkeys, tried opening four different video players, nothing worked.

I`m currently trying to get it work on my mac Lion 10.7.4 but i wouldnt care if there was only a windows solution, I also have here a windows 7 notebook and a windows XP desktop that will help me in the testing period.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this all the time with VLC. I looked it up and the option is not available on Macs but here is the configuration that you need.
http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_play_multiple_instances_of_VLC

I just tested it and it still works like it did before.

Comment: Will he be able to move each running VLC instance to a different monitor?